PermissionError during Virtual Environment Package Installation with pip in Python Script (Windows)
I'm working with a Python script that utilizes pybind11 and includes a function to install a package within a virtual environment. The function, install_package, looks like this:
def install_package(self, package_path, venv_dir):
    """
    Installs a Python package from the given path into a virtual environment.

    Args:
        package_path (str): The path to the directory containing the package to install.
        venv_dir (str): The directory path of the virtual environment.
    """

    # Construct the pip command with flags
    command = ["pip", "install", "--target", venv_dir, "--use-feature=in-tree-build", "--upgrade", "--no-clean", package_path]

    try:
        # Execute the pip command in a subprocess
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Package successfully installed into virtual environment: {venv_dir}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        print(f"Error installing package: {error}")

This function works perfectly when executed directly from a shell script. However, when I call it from within my Python script, I encounter a PermissionError. Here's the complete error message:
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for controller-module, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: controller-module
    Running setup.py install for controller-module: started
    Running setup.py install for controller-module: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed controller-module-3.0.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\project_path\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\project_path\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\project_path\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 446, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "C:\Users\project_path\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 503, in _handle_target_dir
    os.remove(target_item_dir)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied: 'C:\Users\\project_path\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\controller_module.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'

Environment:
Python version (e.g., 3.10)
Operating System (Windows 11)
Why does the install_package function exhibit this permission error only when called from a Python script, and how can I resolve it to ensure successful installation within the script itself?

I fixed it using the following command:
command = [os.path.join("venv", 'Scripts', 'python'), "-m", "pip", "install", "--use-feature=in-tree-build", "--no-clean", package_path]

By specifying the path to the Python interpreter within the virtual environment os.path.join("venv", 'Scripts', 'python'), I ensured that the pip command is executed within the context of the virtual environment. This approach guarantees that the pip executable used is the one associated with the virtual environment, eliminating the need to manually move the package into the virtual environment.

Instead of os.path.join("venv", 'Scripts', 'python') you can use sys.executable which is a more portable approach

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable
